# Why is Hiera not finding the environment, and neither is puppet

Tags: puppet

Given these files:

```
# find /etc/puppetlabs/code -type f | grep -v modules | xargs head -n 100
==> /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/hieradata/common.yaml <==
pgwatch:
  password: "mypass1"
puppetdb:
  password: "mypass2"

==> /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests/site.pp <==
node "todd.ca.seevibes.com" {
  class { 'postgresql::globals':
    encoding            => 'UTF-8',
    locale              => 'en_US.UTF-8',
    manage_package_repo => true,
    version             => '9.1',
  } -> class{'postgresql::server':
  } -> postgresql::server::db{'puppetdb':
    user     => 'puppetdb',
    password => postgresql_password('puppetdb', hiera('puppetdb::password')),
  } -> postgresql::server::db{'pgwatch':
    user     => 'pgwatch',
    password => postgresql_password('pgwatch', hiera('pgwatch::password')),
  }

  postgresql::server::pg_hba_rule{'allow pgwatch from anywhere':
    address     => '0.0.0.0/32',
    auth_method => 'md5',
    database    => 'pgwatch',
    user        => 'pgwatch',
  }
}

==> /etc/puppetlabs/code/hiera.yaml <==
---
:backends:
  - json
  - yaml
:yaml:
  # Use the default value for datadir
  :datadir:
:json:
  # Use the default value for datadir
  :datadir:
:hierarchy:
  - "node/%{::fqdn}"
  - "node/%{::hostname}"
  - "%{::domain}"
  - common
```

I expected the following to return the `pgwatch::password` value:

```
# hiera --debug pgwatch::password
DEBUG: 2015-12-09 22:35:06 +0000: Hiera JSON backend starting
DEBUG: 2015-12-09 22:35:06 +0000: Looking up pgwatch::password in JSON backend
DEBUG: 2015-12-09 22:35:06 +0000: Looking for data source common
DEBUG: 2015-12-09 22:35:06 +0000: Cannot find datafile /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments//hieradata/common.json, skipping
DEBUG: 2015-12-09 22:35:06 +0000: Hiera YAML backend starting
DEBUG: 2015-12-09 22:35:06 +0000: Looking up pgwatch::password in YAML backend
DEBUG: 2015-12-09 22:35:06 +0000: Looking for data source common
DEBUG: 2015-12-09 22:35:06 +0000: Cannot find datafile /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments//hieradata/common.yaml, skipping
nil
```

The same query from Puppet fails as well:

```
# puppet agent -t
Info: Using configured environment 'production'
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Info: Retrieving plugin
Info: Loading facts
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Function Call, Could not find data item puppetdb::password in any Hiera data file and no default supplied at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/manifests/site.pp:10:49 on node todd.ca.seevibes.com
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

In the debug log for hiera, we can clearly see the missing environment in the search paths: `/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments//hieradata/common.json` (notice the double `//` before `hieradata`).

I have found [How do I specify $environment to Hiera on the command line?](https://ask.puppetlabs.com/question/3635/how-do-i-specify-environment-to-hiera-on-the-command-line/) whose best answer says to pass `::environment=production`, which changes nothing. When I pass `environment=production`, then the lookup "succeeds" but returns nothing:

```
# hiera --debug pgwatch::password 'environment=production'
DEBUG: 2015-12-09 22:42:12 +0000: Hiera JSON backend starting
DEBUG: 2015-12-09 22:42:12 +0000: Looking up pgwatch::password in JSON backend
DEBUG: 2015-12-09 22:42:12 +0000: Looking for data source common
DEBUG: 2015-12-09 22:42:12 +0000: Cannot find datafile /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/hieradata/common.json, skipping
DEBUG: 2015-12-09 22:42:12 +0000: Hiera YAML backend starting
DEBUG: 2015-12-09 22:42:12 +0000: Looking up pgwatch::password in YAML backend
DEBUG: 2015-12-09 22:42:12 +0000: Looking for data source common
nil
```

I'm guessing that this time around, the path was correct, and the datafile was found, but the value wasn't returned.

I was expecting a Puppet run to find the value. What am I doing wrong?

```
# uname -a
Linux todd 3.10.23-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64 #1 SMP Mon Dec 9 16:02:37 CET 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
# puppet --version
4.3.1
# hiera --version
3.0.5
# puppet agent --configprint environment
production
# which puppet
/opt/puppetlabs/bin/puppet
# which hiera
/opt/puppetlabs/bin/hiera
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

in your file `/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/hieradata/common.yaml` you need to write `puppetdb::password: mypass2`

In yaml syntax this is a hash not a simple variable

```
puppetdb:
  password: "mypass2"
```

In this way you have a simple variable

```
puppetdb::password: mypass2
```

Comment: // , Why did this fix the problem?

Comment: Puppet looks up parameters in Hiera using fully qualified variable names like `puppetdb::password` rather than expecting nested hashes (`{"puppetdb":{"password":"mypass2"}}`), so the data file wasn't in the right format. See https://docs.puppet.com/hiera/3.2/puppet.html#automatic-parameter-lookup and also the debug lines in the question for the exact key name it's using.